# Probability for random variable that depends on other random variables (deferred decision)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I read a proof which used the following type of argument:

> Assume we draw two random variables $x_1, x_2$ indepenently. Let $y$ be another random variable, that directly depends on $x_1$ and $x_2$ (e.g. $y$ is the sum of both). Suppose that under the assumption, that we have drawn $x_2$ already, the bound $\mathbb{P}(y \leq \varepsilon) \leq \frac{\alpha}{x_2}$ is true. Let $f$ be the pdf for $x_2$. We then get $$ \mathbb{P}(y \leq \varepsilon)\leq \int_0 ^\infty \frac{\alpha}{x_2} f(x_2) \ dx_2 .$$

Intuitively this makes so much sense, but I dont know why exactly this is true. What is the underlying probability theoretic principle that allows us to conclude the second bound?

Comment: I'm having some trouble understanding that bound $\mathbb{P}(y \le \varepsilon) \le \frac{\alpha}{x_2}$.  We have drawn $x_1$, but get a bound that depends on $x_2$?  The value on the left $\mathbb{P}(y \le \varepsilon)$ is a real number, but on the right we have the random variable $\frac{\alpha}{x_2}$, so I'm not sure how to interpret that bound.

Comment: @user6247850 Sorry, it was meant to be $x_2$ instead of $x_1$, I confused the indices. I fixed it now.

Comment: Are you quoting directly? There are many things wrong with the notation in the proof you're quoting; it's writing a conditional probability as though it's unconditional, and it's failing to distinguish between random variables and possible values of those random variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me first clean up the notation in your proof. I am used to writing random variables as capital bold letters so they're easily distinguishable from non-random quantities. I don't insist on that convention, but it *is* important to distinguish a random variable from a possible value it can have. In particular, it makes no sense to integrate with respect to a random variable!

> Assume we draw two random variables $\mathbf X_1, \mathbf X_2$ indepenently. Let $\mathbf Y$ be another random variable, that directly depends on $\mathbf X_1$ and $\mathbf X_2$ (e.g. $\mathbf Y$ is the sum of both). Suppose that under the assumption that we have drawn $\mathbf X_2$ already, the bound $\mathbb{P}(\mathbf Y \leq \varepsilon \mid \mathbf X_2 = x_2) \leq \frac{\alpha}{x_2}$ is true. Let $f$ be the PDF for $\mathbf X_2$. We then get $$ \mathbb{P}(\mathbf Y \leq \varepsilon)\leq \int_0 ^\infty \frac{\alpha}{x_2} f(x_2) \ dx_2.$$

Here, we can use the [law of total probability for continuous random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability#Continuous_case):
$$
   \mathbb P(A) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathbb P(A \mid \mathbf X = x) f_{\mathbf X}(x) \,dx.
$$
In this problem $A$ will be the event $\mathbf Y \le \varepsilon$ and $\mathbf X$ will be $\mathbf X_2$. We should assume that $\mathbf X_2$ can never take on negative values, or else the bound in the question can't possibly hold; therefore it is okay to integrate from $0$ to $\infty$ instead. This gives us
$$
   \mathbb P(\mathbf Y \le \varepsilon) = \int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}(\mathbf Y \leq \varepsilon \mid \mathbf X_2 = x_2) f(x_2) \,dx_2.
$$
Using the inequality $\mathbb{P}(\mathbf Y \leq \varepsilon \mid \mathbf X_2 = x_2) \leq \frac{\alpha}{x_2}$, we get the final bound you wanted.

Comment: Thanks alot! Law of total probability was exactly what I was looking for. The notational mess was caused by notational abuse in the proof and my unawareness of how to formulate conditional probabilities in this case. Thank you for cleaning it up!